# Extract json value on regex on bash script

Tags: bash, shell

How can i get the values inner `depends` in bash script?

****manifest**.py**

```
# Commented lines
{
    'category': 'Sales/Subscription',
    'depends': [
        'sale_subscription',
        'sale_timesheet',
    ],
    'auto_install': True,
}
```

Expected response:

```
sale_subscription sale_timesheet
```

The major problem is linebreak, i have already tried `| grep depends` but i can not get the `sale_timesheet` value.

Im trying to add this values comming from files into a var, like:

```
DOWNLOADED_DEPS=($(ls -A $DOWNLOADED_APPS | while read -r file; do cat $DOWNLOADED_APPS/$file/__manifest__.py | [get depends value])
```

Example updated.

Comment: You should use a dedicated tool like jq.

Comment: Really not a good idea to try to parse JSON with regexes. I would recommend piping your data to another tool.

Comment: That's not even JSON. JSON uses double quotes only, trailing commas are not permitted, and `True` is not a valid boolean.

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then come back and update the question; in particular ... (as @Thomas has pointed out) a valid set of json data, the command you are feeding into `| grep depends`, and confirmation that you're looking to strip all quotes from the final output; last but not least ... the subject mentions `regex` but I don't see any regex's in the actual question (either remove `regex` from the subject or provide the actual regex in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your JSON file:

```json
{
  "category": "Sales/Subscription",
  "depends": [
      "sale_subscription",
      "sale_timesheet"
  ],
  "auto_install": true
}
```

You can get the desired result using `jq` like this:

```
jq -r '.depends | join(" ")' YOURFILE.json
```

This uses `.depends` to extract the value from the `depends` field, pipes it to `join(" ")` to join the array with a single space in between, and uses `-r` for raw (unquoted) output.

Comment: I think this will work, but i have commented lines in some files:
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2

Comment: @LeandroCampos: consider updating the question with a complete set of sample data so we know ***exactly*** what we're dealing with

Comment: @LeandroCampos Then you don't have JSON. Maybe you have Python instead.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a json file and only string then you can use below Regex to find the values. If it's json file then you can use other methods like Thomas suggested.

```
^'depends':\s*(?:\[\s*)(.*?)(?:\])$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/jsqtP5/1)

you can use egrep for this as follows:

```
% egrep -M '^\'depends\':\s*(?:\[\s*)(.*?)(?:\])$' pathTo\jsonFile.txt
```

you can read about [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)

Comment: you may want to show how you'd apply this regex against the given data (eg, via a `sed`, `grep` or `????` command), especially in light of the OPs mention of `regex` but no signs of a regex in the question (ie, OP may not know how to go about applying your regex)

Comment: @markp-fuso thank you for suggestion, I am learning Regex as well and am trying to answer which I can solve.

Answer (score 1):

As @Thomas has pointed out in a comment, the OPs input data is not in JSON format:

```
$ cat manifest.py
# Commented lines                             // comments not allowed in JSON
{
    'category': 'Sales/Subscription',         // single quotes should be replaced by double quotes
    'depends': [
        'sale_subscription',
        'sale_timesheet',                     // trailing comma at end of section not allowed
    ],
    'auto_install': True,                     // trailing comma issue; should be lower case "true"
}
```

And while the title of the question mentions `regex`, there is no sign of a regex in the question.  I'll leave a regex based solution for someone else to come up with and instead ...

One (quite verbose) `awk` solution based on the input looking exactly like what's in the question:

```
$ awk  -F"'" '                              # use single quote as field separator
/depends/      { printme=1 ; next }         # if we see the string "depends" then set printme=1
printme && /]/ { printme=0 ; next}          # if printme=1 and line contains a right bracket then set printme=0
printme        { printf pfx $2; pfx=" " }   # if printme=1 then print a prefix + field #2;
                                            # first time around pfx is undefined; 
                                            # subsequent passes will find pfx set to a space;
                                            # since using "printf" with no "\n" in sight, all output will stay on a single line
END            { print "" }                 # add a linefeed on the end of our output
' json.dat
```

This generates:

```
sale_subscription sale_timesheet
```